# Calling a combobox column in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I have a form whose combobox has two columns, but only one is shown (width 0;1).

If the user selects a row, I want to return the value of the other (hidden) column of the same row. My search showed that you can use the BoundColumn-property to change this, but I want to use the call in VBA itself.

I am trying to program the WHERE-clause:

```
variable = Forms!myFormName!myComboboxName.Column(0)
```

but that won't work.

Can someone tell me what is wrong about that construction?

Thanks in advance.

P.s.:I can provide my complete code if required

Comment: Saying *that doesnt work* isnt enough information. What error does it give you?

Comment: thank you for your critique - it is a "function not defined"-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this problem, see my question answered here:

[Access selecting combobox column in VBA returns "function not defined"-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48867477/access-selecting-combobox-column-in-vba-returns-function-not-defined-error/48869682?noredirect=1#comment84744302_48869682)

Answer (score 0):

use the value property.

```
myComboboxName.value
assuming your bound column is set to 1
```

`.column(0) =` will give you the value of the first column.

`.column(1) =` will give you the value of the second column.

Comment: Hi Krish, thank you for your reply - I appreciate you are trying to help me :) The bound column is column 1, the value I normally want to get from this field, but right now I need the one of column 0...

Comment: Hi Krish, thanks for updating your answer, but that is what I tried to do or do I get your reply wrong? Access tells me this call would be a "non-defined" function, however it should know it. My current code:
 
 'fill the tmpTable only with the Topics of the currently selected Category
strFill = "INSERT INTO tmpTopicTbl ( TopicID, TopicName, CategoryID, CategoryName ) " & _
"SELECT TopicsTbl.TopicID, TopicsTbl.TopicName, TopicsTbl.CategoryID, TopicsTbl.CategoryName " & _
"FROM TopicsTbl " & _
"WHERE ((TopicsTbl.CategoryID) = Forms!frmAdd_Rename_Delete_Topic!CategoryFilterCmb.column(0))